# How to make php code to show what I'm sending to server?

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to upload a jsonarray to a server and then get the response text to see what the server does to the object. On the android side, I have this code:

```
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.2/namedate.php");I am 
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonarray", json_a.toString());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("ProviderTester", "The response text is "+ responseText);
            Log.i("JSONInfo","JSON object: " + json_a.toString());
```

The jsonarray looks like this from the logcat:

```
04-10 21:29:53.293: I/JSONInfo(466): JSON object: ["[name=Mike, datetime=2012-04-10 21:29]","[name=Roger, datetime=2012-04-10 21:29]"]
```

At the moment I am just trying to echo the string and then hopefully later get the table out of the string:

```
   <?php

    echo $_POST['jsonarray'];

   ?>
```

Here are the responses I am getting from the logcat:

```
04-10 22:22:20.033: D/ProviderTester(499): The response text is
```

How do I fix this so I can see the jsonarray string that I am sending to the server?

EDIT: When I change my Android Code to:

```
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_a", json_a.toString()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Then I get the following response in LogCat using the accepted answer for the php script:

```
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): The response text is POST = array (
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'json_a' => '[name=Mike, datetime=2012-04-10 21:29]\\",\\"[name=Roger, datetime=2012-03-10 21:29]\\"]\\"]',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): )
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): GET = array (
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): )
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): request = array (
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Content-Length' => '174',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Host' => 'graasdfon.hostei.com',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'User-Agent' => 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Expect' => '100-Continue',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): )
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): 
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): <!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
```

Now I just need to figure out how to process json_a server side. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> echo $_POST['jsonarray'];

PHP doesn't have a way of doing an implicit toString() representation of a non-scalar data type. You'd need to do an explicit conversion.

e.g. If you want to see all the HTTP variables and the request headers, try something like:

```
<?php

$out="POST = " . var_export($_POST, true) . "\n";
$out.="GET = " . var_export($_GET, true) . "\n";
$out.="request = " . var_export(getallheaders(), true) . "\n";
print $out;

?>
```

(this won't pick up on content written to STDIN but not encloded correctly as a POST)

Comment: thanks for the help! Any idea how to get the information out of json_a server side now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing your issue (I don't know Android/Java), but the best way to debug it would be to simply to this in PHP:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

This will cause PHP to output everything it received via POST.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the json value in the post's entity. Try this:

```
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(json_a.toString());
httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.setEntity(params);
```

Instead of:

```
httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonarray", json_a.toString());
```

Comment: hmm, I tried this method with all of the different php configurations and the response text is: array(0){}